# cleaning shaft of brass door knob?

Tags: doors, knobs

I have a glass door knob taken apart to clean but wonder do I have to remove the glass knob from the brass shaft in order to clean that piece of brass. I have seen many knobs break removing them and didn't want to immerse the knob in a solution until I ask.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add a picture of the knob and shaft? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: What type solution are you using? As long an not using a solution that may etch glass like HF hydrofluoric acid I don’t think I would worry about the glass, we used to use a cyanid solution to remove the patina on some homes that the owners wanted bright brass, after cleaning and rinsing and drying a clear spray lacquer sealed the brass so it would stay bright for years.